# Invalid Function Error when running Cloud Function of Parse Server on back4app

Tags: parse-cloud-code, parse-server, back4app

The error code is below:

```
{"code":141,"message":"Invalid function: \"test\""}
```

**main.js**

```
 Parse.Cloud.define('test', function(request, response){
     response.success('OK');
 }, function(error){
     response.error(error);
 });
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    Parse.Cloud.run('test', null).then(function(result){
        return res.send(result);
    }, function(error){
        return res.status(400).send(error);
    });
});
```

The Cloud Function defined in **main.js** does not work or isn't called successfully. Are there any dependencies missing to be declared in **main.js** in order to run on ***back4app*** or what?

Comment: Not sure if back4app handles this differently,  but it sounds like your main.js file isn't being included correctly.  Are you sure  your include path in your app.js file is correctly finding the main.js file?

Comment: I didn't know that we need to include the main.js file. Do we need to?

Comment: Sorry, I may have used the wrong wording there. 
In the main app file, when configuring the Parse Server, there is an option to set the main Cloud function file. As so:
`var api = new ParseServer({
    cloud: (process.env.CLOUDPATH) `

Is that path correct in your case?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand one thing here. Back4app Parse Server is configured and handed in ready for you to just deploy your files. For example; when I make a parse query, it works without ever configuring parse server. I'm not sure if I still have to define any paths to the main.js file where cloud functions are meant to be. Are you?

Comment: Right, I'm unaware how back4app works, so you might be right. 
In that case, I'll probably be unable to help further.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand regarding Back4App's Cloud Code functions you won't need to have that "function(error)" within your **main.js**. The error treatment will be represented as an error code in your logs when the function present a problem.

I've done some tests and I'd update your example of **main.js** to be simple like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('test', function(request, response){
     response.success('OK');
 });
```

Then your **app.js** would be valid and you could call that function simply by going to *your_webhost.back4app.io/test* or using REST API.